# change color row item selected in ListBox WindowsForm C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I try via this code (c#, windowsform, VS2017):

```
dynamic model;
private void ListBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Index < 0) return;
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                      e.Font,
                                      e.Bounds,
                                      e.Index,
                                      e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                      e.ForeColor,
                                      Color.LimeGreen);

        e.DrawBackground();

        e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items.OfType<Game>().Select(table => table.name).ElementAt(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MainForm.ListBox_DrawItem()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

To change the color of the row of the selected item of my ListBox (which is blue by default) to another color (here in green)

here is the rendering:
[LisBox: change  color item selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTEKK.png)

But I would like to choose between 4 different objects with a switch, but nothing else works:

```
        dynamic model;
    private void ListBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Index < 0) return;
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                          e.Font,
                                          e.Bounds,
                                          e.Index,
                                          e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                          e.ForeColor,
                                          Color.LimeGreen);

            e.DrawBackground();

            switch (selectedModel)
            {
                case "Game":
                    model = listBox.Items.Cast<Game>().Select(table => table.name).ElementAt(e.Index);
                    break;
                case "Gender":
                    model = listBox.Items.Cast<Gender>().Select(table => table.name).ElementAt(e.Index);
                    break;
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawString(model, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
```

I tried to use without success:
OfType <> and Cast <>

```
model = listBox.Items.Cast<Game>().Select(table => table.name).ElementAt(e.Index);
```

Or

```
model = listBox.Items.OfType<Game>().Select(table => table.name).ElementAt(e.Index);
```

Exception: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Core.dll

Thank you for your help, and if I have not been clear enough I will excuse myself in advance I try to put pictures for my request simplified.

---

**Edit:**

I answer myself, and this may have helped more than one !
I ended up finding a solution (but not very clean I think)
there she is:

```
if (listBox.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(Game))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items.Cast<Game>().Select(table => table.name).ElementAt(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
if (listBox.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(Gender))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items.Cast<Gender>().Select(table => table.name).ElementAt(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Obviously the switch does not work, but I do not understand why?

So if you have a better idea to make it more compact and elegant I'm a taker!
Thank you all,